# PHP- How to include Codeingiter class in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

I have to adapt Codeigniter module to Wordpress. It fetches data with SOAP protocol. It needs to use Codeigniter's csrf_protection.

How to include Codeigniter MY_Controller class in Wordpress?

```
class Balance extends MY_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->config->set_item('csrf_protection', TRUE);

        require_once('addons/libraries/nusoap/nusoap.php');

    }

    ...
```

Comment: Research here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/codeigniter+wordpress?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the methods in the nusoap file and try to make like other libraries setup in codeigniter library folder and then :

```
$this->load->library('nusoap/nusoap')
```

Nusoap is the class name which is in upper case letter start with and call in controller like above.

Or else you can find / download separate controller codeingiter library file from github

check it and mark accepted if it works!.

Thanks